# Fourier Analysis, Getting Waves

Tags: python, numpy, math, signals, fft

I have periodic signal consisted of different waves and I used numpy.fft() to get results. Lenght of this array turned out to be 1023, as I have understood I have to plot the waves indivicually. I don't see how I can plot 1023 waves. Is 1023 waves a sensible number for a signal. How can I get it down to say 10. Because the plot of the fft results are cramped up in 4 areas

I have tried to smooth the fft results but that didn't work.

Comment: Should be 1024, a power of 2.  The FFT transforms the time signal into the superposition of 1024 different components in the frequency domain.  What does "cramped up in 4 areas" mean?  You could have chosen 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, or any other power of 2.  How do you decide what's "sensible"?  It's a good question to ask before you blindly apply the method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the fast Fourier transform algorithm is conceived to get an input array which Len is a power of 2, thus the len of 1023.
However, it is not 1023 waves, but 1023 points of the Fourier transform of your initial data over the reciprocal domain.
It would be great if you could send us the code, the input and the output array which could allow us to help you more precisely.

Comment: How can I go to the waves from the FFT data. I added the code and the input data